# Pig. JsonLoader. Load nested objects without schema

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have jsons and I want to load it to pig. Each json looks like this:

```
{"timeStamp":1397718396509,"requestUid":"534F7D320007","result":
{//many many different objects}
```

And I can't provide schema for field *result* because it's not constant and it's very big. So I want to load it as a chararray, or map, or something - doesen't matter. But it should be loaded because it will be needed later. I've tried something like this:

```
LOAD 'log' USING JsonLoader('timestamp:long, req_id:chararray, result:chararray');
```

But I get an empty *result* field. What is the simplest way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use the json loader that comes with [Elephant Bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/) (from twitter). it will load nested Json without need for specifying the schema ahead of time.

Comment: Example code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074385/multilevel-json-in-pig/17081739#17081739